# How can I test key/value column during unit testing in Rails using rake test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rake, key-value

I have a table (`Dishes`) that has a column (`nutrition_facts`) that stores key/value data (similar to [`hstore` in a PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html) database).

I've defined a new instance of a Dish in my fixtures folder as such:

```
nutrition_facts:
  id: 6
  name: Dish 6
  category: Cat 1
  description: Something about Dish 6
  price: 15.32
  menu_id: 1
  nutrition_facts:
    serving_size:
    calories: 392
```

But I can't seem to make the following assertions work when I run `rake test:units` -- it fails on the first `assert_not_nil`

```
  test "no serving size with calories" do
    dish = dishes(:nutrition_facts)

    assert_not_nil(dish.calories)
    assert_nil(dish.serving_size)
    assert !dish.save, "Saved dish when serving size wasn't defined while calories was"
  end
```

How can I test for the individual `calories` and `serving_size` values without testing the entire `nutrition_facts` field?

In short, I'm trying to test the following validation (from my `dish.rb` file), which works when I run the application in a browser:

```
  # Check 'serving size' isn't blank only if 'calories' is defined
  validates_presence_of :serving_size, :if => Proc.new { |val| !val.calories.blank? }
```

Comment: how did you define this "key/value" thing in your model? via serialize?!

Comment: Yes, via serialize. Once I figured out that keyword, I was able to find the solution on this website [Fixtures and serialized attributes in Ruby on Rails](http://thinkingeek.com/2011/06/16/fixtures-and-serialized-attributes-in-ruby-on-rails/).

I'll post the solution as a formal answer in a few hours.

And thanks for your interest in helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by doing defining my nutrition_facts column's key/value as such:

```
nutrition_facts: <%= {:serving_size => nil, :calories => 33}.to_yaml.inspect %>
```

So in my fixtures, it'll look like this:

```
nutrition_facts:
  id: 6
  name: Dish 6
  category: Cat 1
  description: Something about Dish 6
  price: 15.32
  menu_id: 1
  nutrition_facts: <%= {:serving_size => nil, :calories => 33}.to_yaml.inspect %>
```

With my unit test now looking like this:

```
  test "no serving size with calories" do
    dish = dishes(:nutrition_facts)

    assert_not_nil(dish.calories)
    assert_nil(dish.serving_size)
    assert !dish.save, "Saved dish when serving size wasn't defined while calories was"
  end
```

[Source: Fixtures and serialized attributes in Ruby on Rails](http://thinkingeek.com/2011/06/16/fixtures-and-serialized-attributes-in-ruby-on-rails/)